# Persistent connections for live updates

Tags: javascript

I am working on a web application where I have to make live updates to the pag. When data is inserted, deleted or updated in the server-side database, then the page will be updated. I have heard about persistent connections. I have also tried AJAX using `setTimeInterval()`, but the major problem is that when thousands of requests are sent then the browser will start misbehaving. I need something that will make a single request and keep it open/alive and that request will exchange data between the client and the server.

Comment: I think you can't because javascript function will be loaded again every time browser reload.

Comment: Connections are kept alive by the Server. Check `HTTP/1.1` which allows for Persistent connections.

Comment: Use web sockets, but it's only supported in modern browsers.

Comment: What is your server ?

Comment: I am currently using Localhost that is Xampp for testing my app... I am looking in the XAMPP for HTTP alive but how I do it enable?

Answer (score 1):

You need [PUSH](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Push_technology) from server, aren't you ? This is the ability for a webapp te receive notifications from the server.

There are several options depending on your server.

For example, I would recommend [socket.io](http://socket.io/) for node.js.